# Is information still being sent from a discarded tab in my browser?

Tags: privacy, web-browser

I was connected to my workplace wifi via my personal phone for 10 minutes.

I did not open anything strange that could get me into trouble. I was doing some work. However, when I finished looking up what I was looking for, I realised that one of the tabs I opened the night before was still there (because I forgot to close it). A tab I would rather my boss did not see.

As usual, I always browse with the "private" mode on. Therefore that tab was discarded because of inactivity (among my 18 other opened tabs). I did not reclick on the tab to reload it. I simply closed it as soon as I saw it.

Knowing of all this, was information still being sent to the router of my workplace about what I was browsing the night before?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the code in the site you had previously loaded.  If that site had code to call back to it's servers every few seconds (not too uncommon these days), then yes, that traffic would pass through your corporate routers and your boss would have access to it in theory. Just because you didn't click on the tab and hit the "x" without opening it, doesn't mean that the page tab is not able to communicate with a server just as it is able to when you are viewing it.

Comment: So discarded tabs are still working perfectly. I just thought they were left in the background to minimize the impact on the performance. Thank you!

Comment: yup, it might help to post the website you are worried about here for a more concrete decision though.

Comment: I don't think we can make a definite conclusion based on the provided information. The browser software and settings might eventually prevent such things to happen to prevent extra activity to create higher efficiency for their application. We could come to a better conclusion if we knew what browser the OP was running, the device it was running on, as well as if the OP had changed any settings pertaining the the browser and device performance and other aspects.

Comment: fair enough, my assumptions were for chrome at the time of the posting. @Bimbimbap what's the OS/browser?